# WTD,MTD,YTD query in q/kdb+ with by clause

Tags: kdb

```
q)res:([]date:2020.01.01 2020.05.01 2020.05.03 2020.05.26 2020.05.28;pnl:10 10 10 10 10;name:`john`mary`john`john`mary)
```

Looking to get the WTD,MTD,YTD summed PnL by name to produce the below result

```
q)result:([`john`mary]WTD:10 10;MTD:20 20;YTD:30 20)
```

So below for example gives you the time date intervals, I just can't get the query to work (messing around with bin and xbar) to produce end result

```
q)mtd:(`date$0 + `month$.z.d;.z.d)

q)ytd:("d"$12 xbar "m"$.z.d;.z.d)
```

Comment: what is it about?

Comment: What is your question, what is the context, what are you trying, what problem(error?) do you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

One concise way to do it might be:

```
d:`WTD`MTD`YTD!({sum y where x>=m-(m:max x)mod 7};{sum y where x>=`date$`month$max x};{sum y where x>="d"$12 xbar "m"$max x});

q)exec d .\:(date;pnl) by name:name from res
name| WTD MTD YTD
----| -----------
john| 10  20  30
mary| 10  20  20
```

The use of `max` date here is based on the assumption that if one person has a record on a date then they all will. It would also allow it to work on any historical date for a point-in-time view.

If this is not the case then for the current-day view it might be better to use todays date `.z.D` as the point in time, e.g.

```
d:`WTD`MTD`YTD!({sum y where x>=.z.D-.z.D mod 7};{sum y where x>=`date$`month$.z.D};{sum y where x>="d"$12 xbar "m"$.z.D});
```

If your data is sparse and not everyone has a record on every date, and yet you still want a historical week-to-date, month-to-date, year-to-date then I think the best bet would be to "unsparse" the table such that every name has a record on every date, filled with zero pnl if necessary. Then the `max` approach should work along with a filter on the dates in the table

Comment: Hi Terry

Nice answer! What I was looking for, really appreciate that.

I think though if we changed the table to this:

res:([]date:2020.01.01 2020.05.01 2020.05.03 2020.05.26 2020.05.28;pnl:10 10 10 10 10;name:`john`mary`john`john`john)

now Mary should have zero WTD pnl - but that's not the case in your answer, it seems to fill it with the MTD figure, not sure why

but i think just changing the dictionary where clauses to use within, seems to fix it ..

Comment: Aha - its the max x, is the issue, just need to replace that with .z.d :)

Comment: Yes, good observation. Using `max` assumes that if one person has a record on a day then they all will (which may not be the case). Using `.z.D` will always work for the current day but won't work if you ever need to see the stats on a historical date. I'll edit the answer to explain this